# iOS app fails when running on device - "dyld: Library not loaded" "abort with payload"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, dyld

I'm trying to run a test app on my device, from xcode project written in swift.
The app runs perfectly fine on simulator but when I try to run it on my device (iPhone X) it's broken as soon as it opens.
I looked around online but couldn't find any reference that helped me debug this issue by myself. 
Note that other test apps are working fine from this machine running on the same device, and this app is running well when installed from another mac (using the same code but with different identifier)

The output error mentioned:
dyld: library not loaded ...

threads status:

[image]

Versions:
Xcode - version 11.3.1 (11C504)
macOS Catalina - 10.15.3 (19D76)

Any suggestions on how should I dig into this??

Comment: Need more details here. `dyld: Library not loaded` has more information associated with it that you aren't sharing with us.

Comment: You cannot use embedded frameworks on iOS 13.3.1 if you only have a free developer membership.

Comment: Thanks! @Paulw11 is right, apparently, I had to use a paid developer membership (which was used every time I run it from my colleagues' mac, and that's why it worked from one machine but not from the other...)

Answer (score 1):

you have a dynamic library that needs to be added to the binary build

click on your target - general

look for the part

[image]

Your library needs to be listed there to be loaded